# operator = overload in template class

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, operator-overloading

Im working on matrix template class, and now i should write the "=" operator overload.
What Im trying to do is to delete the matrix that appears in the left side of the '=', and return new one that equals to the matrix that appears in the right side of the '='.

because i can't delete "this" with a distructor, I delete it "manually" in the function. but now i should make a new matrix, therefor i make a new one ("temp") and return it.
The prblem is that "temp" is really return, but it doesn't set in the matrix that appears in the left side of the '='.

The code:

```
Matrix<int> m (3, 4);
    Matrix<int> m2(2, 5);
    m2 = m;
```

This was the main part.

The function:

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T> & Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix<T>& mat)
{
    if (this==&mat)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] this->mat[i];
    }

    delete[] this->mat;

    Matrix<T> * temp = new Matrix<T>(mat.rows, mat.cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < temp->rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < temp->cols; j++)
        {
            temp->mat[i][j] = mat.mat[i][j];
        }

    return *temp;
}


template<class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int row, int col)
{
    rows = row;
    cols = col;
    mat = new T*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new T[cols];
    }
    rester(*this);
}
```

Thx!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::vector` as storage (instead of manal `new` and `delete`), and just accept the copy assignment operator generated by the compiler. It's that easy.

---

If you absolutely want to implement the copy assignment yourself, for *learning*, then just express copy assignment in terms of copy construction.

To do that, first define a `noexcept` swap operation:

```
// In class definition:
friend
void swap( Matrix& a, Matrix& b )
    noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    // swap all data members here
}
```

Then the copy assignment operator can be expressed as simply

```
// In class definition
auto operator=( Matrix other )
    -> Matrix&
{
    swap( *this, other );
    return *this;
}
```

It's popular, an idiom, because it's very simple yet exception safe.

---

Instead of returning a reference, which adds verbosity and some possible marginal inefficiency for no gain, you might want to just use `void` as return type. However, probably for historical reasons, the containers in the standard library require the copy assignment operator to return a reference to self.

Comment: If you swap, won't the original be modified?  Not quite the expected result of an assignment.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis: *which* original.

Comment: Nope. The swap's right hand argument is the local copy called `other`.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Allowing the move if moveable or copy if not.

Comment: I should add <T> eact matrix right?
I have tried to do it like that 
friend void swap(Matrix<T> & a, Matrix<T> & b) noexcept;

template<class T>
void swap(Matrix<T>& a, Matrix<T>& b) noexcept
{
 using std::swap;
 a.rows = b.rows;
 a.cols = b.cols;

 for (int i = 0; i < a.rows; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < a.cols; j++)
  {
   a.mat[i][j] = b.mat[i][j];
  }
}
but im getting unresolved external symbol "void_cdecl swap...."

Comment: @BenHuri: Within the class definition the name `Matrix` stands for `Matrix<T>`, so in this scope you don't need to add `<T>`. However, you do need a *definition* of the swap function. You can write that definition inline in the class definition if you want, as shown above (tech details: it's then a non-member function that can be referred to only via argument-dependent lookup, but that's all that's needed).

Comment: Thx!! :) Ill try it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `this` instead of creating a `temp`.

```
template<class T>
Matrix<T> & Matrix<T>::operator=(Matrix<T>& rhs)
{
    if (this==&rhs)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    // Delete current memory
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] this->mat[i];
    }

    delete[] this->mat;

    this->rows = rhs.rows;
    this->cols = rhs.cols;

    // Allocate new memory
    // Assign values to newly allocated memory.
    this->mat = new int*[rhs.rows];
    for (int = 0; i < rhs.rows; ++i )
    {
       this->mat[i] = new int[rhs.cols];
       for (int j = 0; j < rhs.cols; j++)
       {
           this->mat[i][j] = rhs.mat[i][j];
       }
    }

    // Return *this.
    return *this;
}
```

I would recommend using the suggestion given in [the answer by @Cheersandhth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34824771/434551).

Also use a different name of the argument. Don't confuse with the member variable `mat` and the argument `mat`.

Comment: This is not exception safe. Also, it's needlessly complicated.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I agree on both counts. I am keeping it around to show the OP where in his post he made the mistakes.